# Add a zero before 1 digit number in a column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numbers, digits

I have a column in my pandas dataframe that includes communes of French cities. Here is an example:

| index | Com |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris 3 |
| 2 | Paris 17 |
| 3 | Marseille 5 |
| 4 | Abainville |
| 5 | Aast |
| 6 | Marseille 15 |
| 7 | Lyon 4 |

Except I would like to add a 0 to the single digit numbers to get this:

| index | Com |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris 03 |
| 2 | Paris 17 |
| 3 | Marseille 05 |
| 4 | Abainville |
| 5 | Aast |
| 6 | Marseille 15 |
| 7 | Lyon 04 |

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.Com = df.Com.str.replace(r"\D(\d)$", r" 0\1")
```

You can see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2kVMVe/1). It looks at a non-digit and a single digit afterwards, all at the end of the string. Captures the single digit (in `\1`) and pads it with a 0.

to get

```
>>> df

   index           Com
0      1      Paris 03
1      2      Paris 17
2      3  Marseille 05
3      4    Abainville
4      5          Aast
5      6  Marseille 15
6      7       Lyon 04
```

Answer (score 0):

use `zfill` method to pad zeros.

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df.Com = df.Com.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using Pandas `str.replace` function.

```
df['Com'].str.replace(r"^(\S+)(\s+)(\d)$", r"\g<1>\g<2>0\g<3>")
```

Output will be as follows:

```
   index           Com
0      1      Paris 03
1      2      Paris 17
2      3  Marseille 05
3      4    Abainville
4      5          Aast
5      6  Marseille 15
6      7       Lyon 04
```